# date() class adding line breaks to my date format

Tags: php, html, css

I'm formatting my dates to display in a table for a messaging program, for my website.
It's adding line breaks to the date.  So for example  it should display as this

Tue, 16 Apr 2013

but it's displaying as this, in the table.

Tue,

16

Apr

2013

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $from = "username";
    $subject = "test";
    $date = date('D, d M Y',1366129280);
    echo "<table>
              <tr style='font-weight:bold;'>
                  <td>From</td>
                  <td>Title</td>
                  <td>Date</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td style='width:20%;'><a href='#'>".$from."</a></td>
                  <td style='width:60%;'><a href='#'>".$subject."</a></td>
                  <td style='width:20%;'><a href='#'>".$date."</a></td>
              </tr>
         </table>";
 ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It renders fine for me. Do you have some unknown formatting on your td elements?

Comment: Is the TD too small / causing wrapping?

Comment: Do you have enough width on the <td> for it to not wrap around?  That's my first assumption of what's happening.  Can you show us your CSS?

Comment: I think you will find that if you set the width of your date column it will look fine - I think it's just getting squished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the table may not be wide enough to hold the date. There is nothing about your date call or format that would make it insert newlines. The browser will shrink the size of the table detail (td) down to 20%, even if it means pushing some text onto multiple lines.

Try removing the width specifiers from the td, and see what happens. The subject may still be too large, and squish that column. If so, you could try removing that column temporarily.

In either case, nothing is wrong with your php date code.

Comment: Thank you! It was the column widths!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mbarlocker - your PHP is fine, but it will squish depending on how big your browser is.  Try going to this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL2dH/) and resize your window - you will see that it will automatically go to the next line when it's too small, because of this:

```
<td style='width:20%;'>
```